# Spray.can.server.request-timeout property has no effect

Tags: scala, spray

In my `src/main/resources/application.conf` I include:

```
spray.can.server {
  request-timeout = 1s
}
```

In order to test this, in the Future which is servicing my request I put a `Thread.sleep(10000)`.

When I issue a request, the server waits 10 seconds and responds with no hint of a timeout being sent to the client.

I am not overriding the timeout handler.

Why are my clients (chrome and curl) not receiving a timeout?

Comment: Did you check that your config is being used at all? According to docs it's 20 sec by default (http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-can/configuration/). Set yours to 30sec and see if you get it triggered.

Comment: Also factor in `timeout-timeout = 2 s`.

Comment: It should be working so I suspect that your `application.config` is not being read for some reason.

Comment: Optionally try to print config with: `    akka {
      # Log the complete configuration at INFO level when the actor system is started.
      # This is useful when you are uncertain of what configuration is used.
      log-config-on-start = on
    }

`. From: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/logging.html

Comment: If the problem is that config is not being read you'll need to look at your classpath and/or packaging jar plugin (if applicable).

Comment: I created an answer from my comments because it could be an answer for anyone who has misplaced the file or didn't include it in the package, etc.

Comment: Don't use `Thread.sleep` (or other blocking calls) in your route. It will make your routing actor unresponsive and so you won't be able to process the timeout message in time.

Comment: I.e. if you want to handle the timeout manually. The timeout-timeout should probably still work.

Comment: The sleep was for testing purposes and was not in the dispatcher. I could see concurrent requests successfully processed with delay, but not timeout (because the wrong config file was being read & I didn't actually hit the timeout with the sleep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration looks correct, so Spray request timeout should be working. One of the frequent reasons for it not working is that your config `application.conf` is not being used by the application.

The reasons for config being ignored could be that it's in the wrong place, not included in your classpath, or not included in a JAR that you package.

To troubleshoot first check that default Spray timeout is working. By [default](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-can/configuration) it's 20 sec. Make your code sleep for 30sec and see if you get timeouts triggered.

Check what's in your final config values by [printing it](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/logging.html). Set this in your conf:

```
akka {
  # Log the complete configuration at INFO level when the actor system is started.
  # This is useful when you are uncertain of what configuration is used.
  log-config-on-start = on
}
```

Finally, keep in mind other timeouts like `timeout-timeout = 2 s`.

Comment: I had a different application.conf in my intellij run configuration. The classic mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think the request-timeout is for the http client, if the response is not returned before that value, the client will get a timeout from spray, see the [spary doc](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-can/configuration/)

```
  # If a request hasn't been responded to after the time period set here
  # a `spray.http.Timedout` message will be sent to the timeout handler.
  # Set to `infinite` to completely disable request timeouts.
```

For example, in my web browser, I can got a below message:

```
Ooops! The server was not able to produce a timely response to your request.
Please try again in a short while!
```

If the timeout is long enough, the browser will keep waiting until a response is returned

Comment: No timeout is sent to the client.

Comment: Spray will trigger the timeout handler , which will return to the client, you can find the code here:   spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/server/OpenRequest.scala  ** def timeoutResponse(request: HttpRequest): HttpResponse = HttpResponse(
      status = 500,
      entity = "Ooops! The server was not able to produce a timely response to your request.\n" .....
        "Please try again in a short while!")**